# How to use the same component for create and update

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I had a modal that loads a form, with can create a new reservation on my calendar (a reservation is a day who could had a event, but is not a event yet). When i click on the reserved event, i the modal opens up again and i can delete or edit, i magane to load the data the reserved day had to the form fields, but i cant find a way to separate a update from a create action on the same form.

My submit does:

```
  const onSubmit = async (values) => {
    setSubmitting(true)
    try{
      await createReservedEvent({ variables: {startTime: selectedDay, eventTypeId: values.eventType.value, ...values } })
      handleClose()
      sendNotification(t({id: 'saved-reserved-event'}))
      setSubmitting(false)
    } catch(err) {
      setSubmitting(false)
      sendNotification(t({id: 'failed-save-reserved-event'}), 'error', err)
      throw (err)
    }
  }
```

The await to 'createReservedEvent' calls a mutation with graphql. How do i split this to call a update mutation? Thanks by now

Comment: A way to achieve this is by giving a `event` props to your form (representing the object you are editing). If it's a creation, just pass `null` as `event`. Then, in your `obSubmit` function, you can check if it's a creation or an update (`if (this.props.event) ...`)

Comment: Worked to select if its create or update, thanks. My problem now is with graphql mutation, but the original question is done. thanks.